# facebook FQL CONTAINS operator not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-apps

Since yesterday morning the "CONTAINS" FQL function doesn't work for the application table.

For example, the query: `SELECT link,display_name FROM application WHERE  CONTAINS ('slot')`

the result is: `{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}`

But for the user table query: `SELECT first_name FROM user WHERE  CONTAINS ('ben')`

the result is: `{
  "data": [
    {
      "first_name": "Benjamin"
    }, 
    {
      "first_name": "Benjamin"
    }, 
    {
      "first_name": "Damon"
    }`...

There was no warning or notice about it from FB.

Any one knows what is the reason for that, and how can i search apps using the FB API?

Thanks